# array maniupulation not working when looping through

Tags: javascript, arrays

Basically why is my loop not pushing it in the array correctly, instead of getting one array with 5 indexs, I get 5 separate arrays.

```
var result = ["Hello"];

for(var i = 0; i < result[0].length; i++) {
  var array = [];
  //array[array.length] = (result[0]);
  array.push(result[0]);

  console.log(array); // {"Hello"}{"Hello"}{"Hello"}{"Hello"}{"Hello"}

}

var fruits = [];

fruits.push('apple');
fruits.push('pineapple');
console.log(fruits); // ['apple', 'pineapple']
```

Comment: Your array is being redefined each time the loop is run through. So every time you add to it, it gets redefined to an empty array. You'll need to move it outside the for loop block.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `array` is being redefined every time the loop is run. You need to move your `var array = []` definition outside the for-loop. Currently, every time you add to it, it gets redefined to an empty array.

```
var result = ["Hello"];
var array = [];

for(var i = 0; i < result[0].length; i++) {
  array.push(result[0]);

  console.log(array);
}
```